# Combinar todas as coordenadas x, y, z de uma lista de tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho a seguinte lista com vários pontos:

```
[(14, 9, 7), (11, 1, 20), (1, 1, 7), (13, 9, 1), (9, 13, 4), (20, 1, 4), (17, 6, 8), (14, 10, 1), (14, 2, 17), (7, 20, 7)]
```

Cada elemento da lista é um tuple com as coordenadas (x, y, z), o que eu preciso é de juntar todos os x, y e z para que fique assim:

```
[(x,x,x,x,x...), (y,y,y,y,y,y...), (z,z,z,z,z,z...)]
```

Já tentei assim mas não resultou:

```
lista = []
for i in coords:
    lista.append(i[0])
    lista.append(i[1])
    lista.append(i[2])
```

Mas não resultou ficando todos misturados

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podes fazer, usando [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip):

```
coords = [(14, 9, 7), (11, 1, 20), (1, 1, 7), (13, 9, 1), (9, 13, 4), (20, 1, 4), (17, 6, 8), (14, 10, 1), (14, 2, 17), (7, 20, 7)]

combin = zip(*coords) # aqui fazes unpacking de cada tuple e esta funcao vai juntar todos os indices 0, 1, 2 dos tuples em uma lista separada
print(list(combin))
```

Output:

> [(14, 11, 1, 13, 9, 20, 17, 14, 14, 7), (9, 1, 1, 9, 13, 1, 6, 10, 2, 20), (7, 20, 7, 1, 4, 4, 8, 1, 17, 7)]

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/0mO4is)

Para fazer da maneira que estavas a tentar também é possível, estavas é a fazer confusão com a operação dentro do ciclo, deves criar 3 listas diferentes que vão armazenar os x's, y's, e z's respetivamente:

```
lista = [[],[],[]] # [[x,x,x..], [y,y,y..], [z,z,z..]]
for x, y, z in coords: # fazer o unpacking de cada tuple
    lista[0].append(x)
    lista[1].append(y)
    lista[2].append(z)
print(lista)
```

Output:

> [[14, 11, 1, 13, 9, 20, 17, 14, 14, 7], [9, 1, 1, 9, 13, 1, 6, 10, 2, 20], [7, 20, 7, 1, 4, 4, 8, 1, 17, 7]]

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/XiJTPe)

Se precisares que cada lista interna seja mesmo um tuple, depois de realizada a operação `for`, basta fazer:

```
lista = [tuple(i) for i in lista]
```

Mas nota que a primeira é mais correta/pythonica, esta ultima é para perceberes que também dá e qual a lógica a adotar para isto.